# Como tirar o último mais "+" que me aparece na consola partindo deste código?

Tags: java

Será que alguém me consegue dizer como tirar o último mais  "+" que me aparece na consola partindo deste código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Power2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Valor [1..2^31] ?"); 
        int valor = input.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;valor<0;i++){
            System.out.println("Valor [1..2^31] ?"); 
            valor=input.nextInt();
        }
        int[] array=new int[31];
        int[] arrayvalor=new int[31];
        int resto;
        int ndivisoes=0;

        for(int i=0;valor>0;i++){    
            resto=(valor%2);
            System.out.println("resto= "+resto);
            valor=valor/2;
            System.out.println(valor);
            array[i]=resto;
            ndivisoes=i;
            arrayvalor[i]=valor;
            //System.out.println(arrayvalor[i]);
            //System.out.println("i= "+i);
        }
        int count=ndivisoes;

        for(int j=ndivisoes;j>=0;j--){
            String soma=" ";
            if(array[j]==1){
                if(j==0){
                    soma=" ";
                    System.out.print(2+"^"+j+soma);    
                }else{
                    soma="+";
                    System.out.print(2+"^"+j+soma);

                }                      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução simplificada:

```
   ...
}
int count=ndivisoes;
// Mantive a linha acima, que não é usada, apenas para você ver de onde eu comecei o código.

String soma="";
for(int j=ndivisoes;j>=0;j--){
    if(array[j]==1){
        System.out.print(soma+"2^"+j);
        soma="+"; // por estética pode usar soma=" + "; se preferir
    }
}
```

[Clique aqui](http://ideone.com/hYtkCM) para ver o resultado no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hYtkCM)**.

Comment: Para 6 o resultado foi `2^2+2^1+` com o `+` no final. Não está faltando nada no código?

Comment: @LucasNunes com esse código que eu postei, é impossível um "+" no final. Certifique-se de copiar e colar ele na íntegra para testar.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi do seu código, ele funciona bem quando o menor valor de `j` para o qual `array[j] == 1` é `0`, e funciona mal (exibe o `+` a mais) quando o menor `j` para o qual `array[j] == 1` é `> 0`.

Então na verdade você não quer usar a condição `if (j == 0)`, e sim `if (j == x)` onde `x` é o menor valor de `j` para o qual `array[j] == 1`.

Minha sugestão é que você crie um método que recebe como parâmetro `array` e retorna a menor posição do `array` para a qual `array[posição] == 1`, e use esse resultado no seu `if`.

Não sei se a minha lógica é a melhor forma de fazer, mas ela ilustra o problema e você pode trabalhar no código para melhorá-lo a partir do que essa lógica está evidenciando.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver esse problema não adicionando `+` e, em vez disso, adicionar espaços. Depois você faz um `trim()` para eliminar os possíveis espaços após o valor e substitui os espaços por `+`.

Eu fiz o seguinte aqui:

```
    String soma=" ";

    for(int j=ndivisoes;j>=0;j--)
    {
        if(array[j]==1)
        {
            soma += "2^" + j + " ";
        }
    }

    soma = soma.trim();
    soma = soma.replace(' ', '+');
    System.out.println(soma);
```

A saída foi:

```
Valor [1..2^31] ?
6
resto= 0
3
resto= 1
1
resto= 1
0
2^2+2^1
```

Answer (score 0):

Nada te garante que `array[j] == 1` na última iteração do laço, e essa é a condição necessária pra que você defina a variável `soma` como `" "`.

Minha abordagem do problema considera como caso especial a primeira impressão na saída e não a última. Porque sabemos que após alguma coisa já ter sido enviada para a tela podemos colocar um `"+"` à frente das próximas coisas que vamos imprimir.

Dessa maneira basta utilizar um flag para nos sinalizar quando algo foi impresso.

Veja o algoritmo corrigido:

```
boolean foiImpresso = false;
for (int j = ndivisoes; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (array[j] == 1) {
        if (foiImpresso) {
            System.out.print(" + 2^" + j);
        } else {
            System.out.print("2^" + j);
            foiImpresso = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja que a varíavel `soma` não foi utilizada pois é completamente desnecessária. Leve em consideração que não testei este algoritmo, estou apenas supondo que está correto.